# How do I solve an -228 download error when installing a FireFox addon?

Tags: firefox, amazon-s3

Our online application requires that users install a web browser plugin, and I have several plugins hosted on S3 for people to download, and one of them is for Firefox. While the other plugins can download and install fine, the FF plugin causes Firefox to display this error:

```
Download error -228
```

I am able to download and install other plugins and addons using the browser without getting this error. The plugin is less than 100k. I've moved the plugin to another server (not S3) and get the same "Download error -228" error again. I've recompiled the plugin and that doesn't help either.

[Here's a posting that describes the same thing I'm experiencing](https://forums.addons.mozilla.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=490&p=1768&hilit=download+228#p1768) (and the poster didn't find an answer either, :\ )

This has me truly stumped. Any suggestions or fixes will be eagerly attempted!

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It's gotta be something weird with the browser. Mozilla says that this is due to the cache being disabled. Which doesn't really seem to be the case seeing as how you were able to install other plugins...

Download Error -228
Disabled cache

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/unable+to+install+add-ons#Download_Error_228

The next steps I would take are to try Firefox on another machine. Then to update / upgrade or reinstall the browser.

If that doesn't fix it, then double check your code.

Hope that helps.